# How to initialize a dynamic double array elements to 0 in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I tried the following two approaches. When I test it in a small program, both seem to work. But it could be possible that memory is coming from the OS which will be zeroed by default.

Approach1:

```
int n_var = 1000;
double *vars = malloc(n_var*sizeof(*vars));
if(!vars) die("Memory error."); 
memset(vars, 0, n_var*sizeof(*vars));
```

Approach2:

```
int n_var = 1000;
double *vars = calloc(n_var, sizeof(*vars))
if(!vars) die("Memory error.");
```

Could anybody confirm if the above are correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, nothing mandates that the representation of 0.0 is all bit clear and thus you should initialize explicitly.
Practically, the most common double formats have this property and both ways will works.

Comment: IEEE 754 is pretty common, I think the OP will be ok.

Comment: @Carl  - IEEE 754 is pretty common _today_.  What about five years from now, or ten, or fifty?  Who knows what CPU architecture will be in vogue?  Code to the spec unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: @CarlNorum, do you have checked that the decimal formats introduced by IEEE 754-2008 still have it (I haven't)?

Comment: @Nemo, that's quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately all bytes zero is not the representation of zero for float or double types.
The only way to do this is by iteration over the elements and setting then to zero manually.

Comment: Mantisa=0 exponent =0 implies mantisa * base^exponent, for mantisa=0 I think value should be zero.

Comment: If you need to be portable to machines without IEEE floating point, maybe.  Do you know of any?